# Adobe-Brackets disable auto-indent and auto-close tags

Tags: tags, indentation, adobe-brackets, auto-indent, auto-close

I have an issues with Adobe Brackets out there after trying to change the preferences with solutions that are out there.

Issue:

I opened with the head tag. After typing some code, on the last line, i begin to close the head tag and it auto completes the tag.

In addition, it auto-indents the closing tag.

How do I disable both of these? I have tried changing the preferences 
smartIndent, whenClosing, whenOpening all to 'false' but to no avail. Or perhaps I need an idiot-proof explanation of how to do it.

Update:

The auto-indent of the tag seem to follow the previous written line of code. I would like to prevent this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Brackets Wiki Preferences page](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences) details the `closeTags` option, which, to disable the particular behavior you're experiencing, should have the `whenClosing` option disabled, at least.

Add this to your preferences file:

```
"closeTags": {
    "whenClosing": false
}
```

Additionally, to disable tag autoclosing when typing the opening tag, disable `whenOpening`, as well:

```
    "whenOpening": false
```